# The request body contains invalid JSON. discord api

Tags: php, laravel, discord

i make a request to discord it's give me the error:

> The request body contains invalid JSON;

here is my example:

```
try {
        $join = new Client();
        $joinData = $join->put($this->baseURL . "guilds/" . $this->tokenData['serverId'] . "/members/" . $socialUser->id,
            ['headers' => ['content-type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'Bot ' . Discord::$botToken]]);
      } catch (Exception $th) {
          dd("join Error :" . $th->getMessage());
      }
```

[image: the error]

expecting status 200

Comment: `"guilds/"` is this correct? `"/guilds/"` prob? What is your baseURL? Does it end with `/`?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `put` method in your Client class. It looks like your request has no body based on the code you show, but the API is saying your request has invalid JSON.

Comment: It's a popular PHP package named Guzzle, PHP HTTP client.